# Mssql err: Column 'dbo.History.Email' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

when executing this MSSQL statement it forces me to add the CASE WHEN field History.Email in the group by field, however I need to group only on a date field.
Any idea how this can be solved? (sql 2008)

```
SELECT     TOP (100) 

convert(varchar, VisitDate, 111) as Date, 
SUM(AmountLoaded) AS Loaded, 

CASE when History.Email is null then
              SUM(AmountCash) 
       else   SUM(AmountToPay)  
       end    AS Total,
                    
CASE when History.Email is null then
              0
       else   SUM(AmountToPay)
       end    AS App,
                                                         
SUM(AmountToPay) AS Consumed
                       
FROM       dbo.History
GROUP BY   convert(varchar, VisitDate, 111)
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Reminder: SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for as good as 2 years now; you should really be looking at upgrades paths by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing conditional aggregation you need to put the *entire* `CASE` expression in an aggregate, not just the expression(s) you want to aggregate:

```sql
SELECT TOP (100)
       CONVERT(varchar(10), H.VisitDate, 111) AS [Date], --Always specify a length/precision/scale for your data types
       SUM(H.AmountLoaded) AS Loaded,
       SUM(CASE WHEN H.Email IS NULL THEN H.AmountCash ELSE H.AmountToPay END) AS Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN H..Email IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE H.AmountToPay END) AS App,
       SUM(H.AmountToPay) AS Consumed
FROM dbo.History H
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), H.VisitDate, 111) --Always specify a length/precision/scale for your data types
ORDER BY [Date] DESC; --Be specific, don't use ordinal positions
```

Note, as well, I suggest *not* converting your column `VisitDate` to a `varchar` in your query. If you want to **display** the data in a specific format then that's something for your presentation layer to do, *not* the RDBMS. Fortunately, as style `111` is `yyyy/MM/dd` then the order of the data isn't affected. If, however, you want to simply truncate the time portion of your value, convert it to a `date` so that the value continues to remain strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

By definition any nonaggregate fields should be in the group by clause. You can write that as:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) 
convert(varchar, VisitDate, 111) as Date, 
SUM(AmountLoaded) AS Loaded, 
SUM(CASE when History.Email is null 
         then AmountCash 
         else AmountToPay end)    AS Total,
SUM(CASE when History.Email is null 
         then 0
         else AmountToPay
         end)    AS App,
SUM(AmountToPay) AS Consumed
FROM       dbo.History
GROUP BY   convert(varchar, VisitDate, 111)
order by 1 desc
```